# Tomcat and java.net.ServerSockets

Tags: tomcat, serversocket

Is there anything, what can block me using the `java.net.ServerSockets` on the `Tomcat` server? As i understand it, the Tomcat is used mainly for http based communication servlet, but raw sockets can be used as well, right?

Regards,
STeN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to inside the scope of a Servlet then that's definitely asking for trouble. Threads in Tomcat are recycled and this will basically block other requests from using your thread (at least until your thread's request times out). You can, of course create a new thread and bind it to a port (if your Tomcat user has permissions) outside of the request/response cycle but you may want to look into creating a custom Tomcat connector instead.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for such a prompt response. I am new to this topic... 1/ Can you please tell me if use of the Tomcat for the TCP connections brings me any advantage comparing to the pure standalone java server? 2/ Do you have any links/references regarding creating the custom Tomcat connectors? 3/ Can be Tomcat hosting somehow configured in a way to not allow custom connectors, so I will not be able to run my war file? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Tomcat is a Servlet container, so its advantage is only if you are dealing with HTTP requests (such as from a browser).

Comment: 3. If you're on a shared/hosted Tomcat you'll most likely not be able to do any kind of configuration with custom connectors (nor bind to network ports).

Comment: Thanks a lot for perfect answers!! I have very last question. There is AWS Elastic Beanstalk service (http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/), which allows as I understand Tomcat war files deployment in cloud. Do you think/know if there is the same limitation as on the shared/hosted Tomcat environment?

Comment: Yeah, as long as you are limited to deploying war files you most likely cannot modify base Tomcat settings. You'd have to roll your own EC2 instance to do that.

Comment: Thanks. I will look on EC2 - looks that this is the service I am looking for... Kind Regards